# JQuery Draggable to Drag to Position Programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to add buttons somewhere on the page to manipulate JQuery Draggable element without mouse dragging, i.e. programmatically. In other words, I want to shift (or pan) draggable element inside its container up or down, left or right depending on what button user clicks. How can I do it? I cannot seem to find that option in docs. Do I simply manipulate CSS left/top to achieve it and make sure I do not go outside of the container?

```
$(".drag-view").draggable({drag:function(event, ui){containment:a /*...*/}});
```

Comment: Draggable doesn't provide that interface.  You'll need to do it with a separate script.  It will not fire the `stop` event for you, so you'd need to trigger that manually if you needed it to fire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could draw the element on the screen and then use $.animate() to move it into position. The element would have to be positioned absolutely to animate in that fashion and would, as you mentioned, be a result of top and left.

Comment: Travis, do you think he needs to consider triggering the `stop` event, depending on what his code is doing?

Comment: @cale_b - I guess that would depend on his requirements. Stop could be used if the animation was going to be cut short by a dragging event.